# Can I use a StringIndexer without One-Hot-Encoding it in PMML (exporting from Spark)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, pmml

I'm trying to take a functional, fitted SparkML pipeline (Scala, Spark 2.1.1 for compatibility reasons) and turn it into PMML for interoperability and storage purposes.

At the moment, the pipeline has the following form: Array(StringIndexer,StringIndexer,VectorAssembler,VectorIndexer). I've tried the standard org.jpmml.sparkml.PMMLBuilder which works perfectly fine in situations where I'd already indexed the strings on the database. (I know how many distinct strings there are in these columns, and I'm completely certain that they'll stay categorical.) I'm planning on using them in a decision tree and a few other tree-based methods, and SparkML has lovely treatment of categorical variables in trees that make one-hot-encoding less than ideal.

```scala
val strCols = Array("stringCol1","stringCol2")

val strIndexers = strCols.map(c => new StringIndexer().setInputCol(c).setOutputCol(c+"_Indexed"))

val collist = df.columns.diff(strCols) ++ strCols.map(c => c+"_Indexed")

val vectorAssembler = new VectorAssembler() 
    .setInputCols(collist)
    .setOutputCol("rawFeatures")

val vectorIndexer = new VectorIndexer().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features").setMaxCategories(35)

val pipeintro = new Pipeline().setStages(strIndexers :+ vectorAssembler :+ vectorIndexer)
val pipeIntro = pipeintro.fit(df)

val pmmlBuilder = new org.jpmml.sparkml.PMMLBuilder(df.schema, pipeIntro).buildFile(new File("out.pmml"))
```

I expected the code to complete running and output the appropriate PMML, but what I get instead is:

```scala
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field stringCol1 has valid values [MT, IP, OB, GA, ED, OP]
  at org.jpmml.converter.PMMLEncoder.toCategorical(PMMLEncoder.java:209)
  at org.jpmml.sparkml.feature.VectorIndexerModelConverter.encodeFeatures(VectorIndexerModelConverter.java:80)
  at org.jpmml.sparkml.FeatureConverter.registerFeatures(FeatureConverter.java:47)
  at org.jpmml.sparkml.PMMLBuilder.build(PMMLBuilder.java:114)
  at org.jpmml.sparkml.PMMLBuilder.buildFile(PMMLBuilder.java:292)
```

I've checked for null values; there are none, nor are there other values that are invalid. There's some indication somewhere that StringIndexers are supposed to be one-hot-encoded before being put into a VectorAssembler, but that's suboptimal for this particular pipeline since it's intended to feed into a SparkML-defined tree, which deals well with multi-value categorical columns. Is that guidance hard-coded into PMML or the Spark-PMML encoder? Is there some other error that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

This particular exception is about conflicting "stringCol1" definition - its value space has been defined by `StringIndexer` ([MT, IP, OB, GA, ED, OP]), and now `VectorIndexer` is trying to re-define it with a different value space. One of those attempts is wrong.

Could be a bug of the JPMML-SparkML library, or your script. Perhaps the output of `StringIndexerModel` shouldn't be VectorIndexed at all?

Comment: Hm. Odd... VectorIndexer doesn't get stringCol1, it gets a vector that includes stringCol1Indexed instead. (At least, collist, the input for VectorAssembler, has stringCol1Indexed instead of stringCol1.)

Comment: (Actually, I mistyped. It's stringCol1_Indexed not stringCol1Indexed.)

Comment: JPMML-SparkML keeps track of feature definitions internally. It knows that "stringCol1" contains string category levels (listed in the exception message), and gets confused when VectorIndexer attempts to replace them with integer category levels (0, 1, .., ncat).

Comment: If you filter `StringIndexerModel` output column through `VectorIndexer`, then you're actually working against your original intent - applying decision tree learner to string data, no?

Comment: "StringIndexer encodes a string column of labels to a column of label indices. The indices are in [0, numLabels), ordered by label frequencies, so the most frequent label gets index 0." (From the docs.) The output of StringIndexer is a categorical but numerical column. But the indexed strings aren't the only variables that need to go into the tree model; there are several other things that are actually numeric. PMML explicitly doesn't allow me to assemble a vector from a vector and non-vector columns, so I can't assemble and index the numerics, then add the strings.

Comment: "PMML explicitly doesn't allow me to assemble a vector from a vector and non-vector columns". Interesting observation - do you have some code exemplifying the problem? If you do, please open a feature request with the JPMML-SparkML project.

Comment: That's actually an intentional design decision on the part of the people who made PMML, as far as I can tell. (I read some commentary a couple of months ago on the subject; from what I remember, it was something along the lines of "You shouldn't feed in a set of nameless columns into an algorithm, what happens if some part of the data feed switches their positions.")